# Eliminate redundant letters in string? (e.g. gooooooooood -> good)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to set up some sample data for a Naive Bayesian Classifier for Twitter.

One of the post-processing of the tweets I'd like to do is to remove unnecessary repeat characters.

For example, one of the tweets reads: `Twizzlers. mmmmm goooooooooooood!`

I'd like to reduce the number of w's down to just two. Why two? That's what the article I'm following did. Any individual word that is less than 2 characters is discarded (see mmmmm above). And as far as gooooooood, I would imagine double letters are the most common to be uber repeated.

So, that said, what's the fastest way (in terms of execution time) to reduce words such as gooooooooood to simply good?

[Edit]
I'll be processing 800,000 tweets in this app, hence the requirement for fastest execution
[/Edit]

[Edit2]
I just ran some simple benchmarking based on elapsed time to iterate through 1000 records & save to a text file. I repeated this iteration 100 times on each method. The average results are here:

Method 1: 386 ms [LINQ - answer was deleted]
Method 2: 407 ms [Regex]
Method 3: 303 ms [StringBuilder]
Method 4: 301 ms [StringBuilder part 2]

Method 1: LINQ (answer was apparently deleted)

```
static string doIt(string a)
    {
        var l = a.Select((p, i) => new { ch = p, index = i }).
            Where(p => (p.index < a.Length - 2) && (a[p.index + 1] == p.ch) && (a[p.index + 2] == p.ch))
            .Select(p => p.index).ToList();
        l.Sort();
        l.Reverse();

        l.ForEach(i => a = a.Remove(i, 1));

        return a;
    }
```

METHOD 2:

```
Regex.Replace(tweet,@"(\S)\1{2,}","$1$1");
```

Method 3:

```
static string StringB(string s)
    {
        string input = s;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < 2 || input[i] != input[i - 1] || input[i] != input[i - 2])
                sb.Append(input[i]);
        }
        string output = sb.ToString();
        return output;

    }
```

Method 4:

```
static string sb2(string s)
    {
        string input = s;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(input);

        char p2 = '\0';
        char p1 = '\0';

        int pos = 0, len = sb.Length;
        while (pos < len)
        {
            if (p2 == p1) for (; pos < len && (sb[pos] == p2); len--)
                    sb.Remove(pos, 1);

            if (pos < len)
            {
                p2 = p1;
                p1 = sb[pos];
                pos++;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: How would you know the person didnt mean God? as in, Gooooooooooooooood? I don't see any way to do this with a 100% accurate outcome.

Comment: @FB - I can't guarantee 100% accuracy. I'm just following what some guys from Stanford did

Comment: @Matt - I need to programmatically do this for any repeat characters... not just gooooooooood

Comment: Is this about english language only  ?

Comment: Yes the tweets will be in english only.

Comment: @F.B.tenKate because thats godddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd not gooooooooooooooooooooooooooood :)

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks, I've always wanted to be nominated for an award.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexen look to be the simplest. Simple proof of concept in the REPL:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  
var regex = new Regex(@"(\S)\1{2,}"); // or @"([aeiouy])\1{2,}" etc?
regex.Replace("mmmmm gooood griieeeeefff", "$1$1");
```

-->

```
"mm good griieeff"
```

For raw performance, use something more like this: **see it live on https://ideone.com/uWG68**

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "mmmm gooood griiiiiiiiiieeeeeeefffff";

        var sb = new StringBuilder(input);

        char p2 = '\0';
        char p1 = '\0';

        int pos = 0, len=sb.Length;
        while (pos < len)
        {
            if (p2==p1) for (; pos<len && (sb[pos]==p2); len--)
                sb.Remove(pos, 1);

            if (pos<len)
            {
                p2=p1;
                p1=sb[pos];
                pos++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: a bit later than anticipated, but hey, the approach should be pretty swift :)

Comment: 2ms faster per iteration in 200 total iterations. This is the winner.

Comment: @ScottSilvi: I bet my solution would still win if you initialize the `StringBuilder` with an initial capacity of the length of the input.

Comment: also, think of compiling with optimization; always profile your code (for inputs with frequent and long sequences of repeated characters, you could count them and remove the subsequence in one call to `sb.Remove(pos, toBeRemoved)` instead of char-per-char

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I suspect the outcome then really be equivalent for optimizing compilers. My use of p1,p2 to cache the last characters might be an advantage though if characters are very likely to be repeated many times. However, like I suggest, it is about 'profiling'; not so much about  'guessing the right approach' (I do appreciate the art of getting it 'mostly' right the first time though :))

Comment: True, true - indexer access probably has a little more overhead - it doesn't help readability in this case though ;-) But I concede on a pure performance point of view these "dirty tricks" probably are needed, even though they are highly dependent on how the compiler optimizes - I just can't get myself to go there. +1 from me for going all the way ;)

Comment: @sehe - I will test further tonight. Off to run errand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Nah, going all the way would entail working on a raw `char[]` with _unsafe_ code (`char*` anyone?). That is going to be significantly faster. You could even assume a character encoding (<whistle/>) and work directly on `encoding.GetBytes(input)` with `byte*`. You're guaranteed not to have to reallocate. Anyways, it's turd polishing either way !

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I ran 10000 records 100 times, and 1000 records 1000 times (for 1M total) and both times sehe's code won out by between 4% & 5%. There may be variables I'm not considering here, but for now, I have to give the win to sehe. Thanks for your help you two. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is also (easily) doable via a regular expression:

```
var re = @"((.)\2)\2*";
Regex.Replace("god", re, "$1")    // god
Regex.Replace("good", re, "$1")   // good
Regex.Replace("gooood", re, "$1") // good
```

Is it faster than the other approaches? Well, that's for the benchmarks ;-) Regular expressions can be quite efficient in non-degenerate backtracking situations. The above may need to be altered (this will also match spaces for instance), but it's a small example.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that this will not work in the general case, especially in "Twitter speak". Having said that the rules you mentioned are simple - eliminate every character that is the same as the previous two characters:

```
string input = "goooooooooooood";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
sb.Append(input.Substring(0, 2));

for (int i = 2; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i] != input[i - 1] || input[i] != input[i - 2])
        sb.Append(input[i]);
}
string output = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Is that the fastest in terms of execution? I'll update my question to reflect that I will be parsing 800,000 lines of tweets, so speed is optimal (which I did mention)

Comment: @Scott: Why don't you implement it, test it, and find out for yourself?  You'll have to learn how to optimize your own code sooner or later.

Comment: @Ed - well I suppose that's why I came here. Given that I didn't know how to do it before I came here, it would be kind of hard to implement, test, refactor, rewrite, improve, etc, when you don't know how to do something to begin with. Or how to improve it...

Comment: @ScottSilvi: I can't make the statement that this would be **the** fastest way to do it (if I would make a guess most likely not), but at least it will traverse the input string only once and will not generate new strings while doing it - both common pitfalls.

Comment: No, you don't (shouldn't) come here for "teh codez", you come here for guidance after you have put in some effort.  How to you expect to develop as an engineer if you are handed everything on a silver platter?  Do you think the person who gives you an answer didn't figure this stuff out over time?

Comment: @Ed - First of all, I've put in almost 1,000 hours into this project (on my own time) since Sept 2010, so I'd say I've put in plenty of effort. As far as this particular component, I was guessing it was a regex, but despite efforts to master/understand it, it's remained elusive. I spent a few hours googling it this morning, came up with a few linq solutions I wasn't particularly fond of, and figured I'd come here, rather than continue to beat my head against a wall. Thank you for the lecture on how to become a better engineer. When your book comes out, I'd be happy to contribute...

Comment: @Scott: I'll be sure to send you an advance copy.

Comment: Thanks. appreciated. For what its worth, now that I have several solutions I can test, I've been able to put it through some simple benchmarking (which I'm sure you can poke holes in) to find what appears to be the fastest solution. So Thanks.

Comment: @ScottSilvi: Please share the benchmarks by editing your question, I'd be interested in the results

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I will, and you've won. Congrats :)

Comment: @Scott: you can't know. I suggest that my solution is quicker :) (I have _not_ benchmarked it, but hey, please share the results!)

Comment: I'm currently iterating through the methods 100 times to get an aggregate. Will post shortly.

Comment: 100 times? That's way too low. For this type of synthetic benchmarks, you should do tens of thousands of iterations to get any kind of realistic average number (think about the impact of GC). Perhaps you meant that you call the whole test suite 100 times? (-- I usually let pragmatism define the number of test cycles: any order of magnitude that stays under, say, 5 minutes for the slowest variant is my popular pick)

Comment: well it was was run 100 times but each iteration was run 1000 times, so ultimately each method was run 100k times.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into NLP solutions rather than C#/regex. In that world, python is preferred. See [NLTK](http://nltk.org). I would recommend [Nodebox Linguistics](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#spelling) which gives you spelling corrections. You can even stem words and even go down to the infinitive.

Comment: Yeah I've looked into NTLK & have read much of the book they provide. I imagine the long-term solution for this will be to use python & NTLK, but until I have the time to learn python & how to integrate it into our technology stack, I have to do the best with what I have